# KeyError: '_id' CRITICAL ('Exception writing records', KeyError('_id')) Singer.io

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-redshift, etl, singer-io

I got this error while doing ELT from mongo-tap to redshift. When I simply extract data from MongoDB to CSV it works fine. but when piping out output to redshift I am getting this _id error. not sure what is the reason. Can anybody guide me
More detail https://github.com/singer-io/tap-mongodb/issues/48. As it has been written in python so need help from the python community as well.

I have setup tap-mongo via instructions [here](https://github.com/singer-io/tap-mongodb).  I am running this command to export

```sh
~/.virtualenvs/tap-mongodb/bin/tap-mongodb \
  --config ~/Documents/tap/config.json \
  --catalog ~/Documents/tap/catalog.json | \
~/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/bin/target-redshift \
  -c ~/Documents/target/config-redshift.json
```

running this command gives me this error.

```
ERROR Exception writing records
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/postgres.py", line 300, in write_batch
    {'version': target_table_version})
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/sql_base.py", line 808, in write_batch_helper
    for table_batch in denest.to_table_batches(schema, key_properties, records):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/denest.py", line 21, in to_table_batches
    key_properties)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/denest.py", line 47, in _get_streamed_table_schemas
    key_prop_schemas[key] = schema['properties'][key]
KeyError: '_id'
CRITICAL ('Exception writing records', KeyError('_id'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/postgres.py", line 300, in write_batch
    {'version': target_table_version})
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/sql_base.py", line 808, in write_batch_helper
    for table_batch in denest.to_table_batches(schema, key_properties, records):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/denest.py", line 21, in to_table_batches
    key_properties)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/denest.py", line 47, in _get_streamed_table_schemas
    key_prop_schemas[key] = schema['properties'][key]
KeyError: '_id'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/bin/target-redshift", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_redshift/__init__.py", line 55, in cli
    main(args.config)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_redshift/__init__.py", line 49, in main
    target_tools.main(redshift_target)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/target_tools.py", line 28, in main
    stream_to_target(input_stream, target, config=config)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/target_tools.py", line 77, in stream_to_target
    raise e
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/target_tools.py", line 64, in stream_to_target
    line
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/target_tools.py", line 152, in _line_handler
    state_tracker.flush_stream(line_data['stream'])
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/stream_tracker.py", line 41, in flush_stream
    self._write_batch_and_update_watermarks(stream)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/stream_tracker.py", line 67, in _write_batch_and_update_watermarks
    self.target.write_batch(stream_buffer)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_redshift/redshift.py", line 72, in write_batch
    return PostgresTarget.write_batch(self, nullable_stream_buffer)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/target_postgres/postgres.py", line 309, in write_batch
    raise PostgresError(message, ex)
target_postgres.exceptions.PostgresError: ('Exception writing records', KeyError('_id'))
```

Redshift.config

```
   {
   "redshift_host":"redshift-cluster-1.cepdr3dnmmcm.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com",
   "redshift_port":5439,
   "redshift_database":"dev",
   "redshift_username":"awsuser",
   "redshift_password":"Password",
   "redshift_schema":"singer",
   "default_column_length":1000,
   "target_s3":{
      "aws_access_key_id":"*Aws key id*",
      "aws_secret_access_key":"*aws access key*",
      "bucket":"singer-redshift",
      "key_prefix":"__tmp"
   },
   "schema":{
      "properties":{
         "_id":{
            "minimum":-2147483648,
            "inclusion":"automatic",
            "maximum":2147483647,
            "type":[
               "null",
               "integer"
            ]
         },
         "name":{
            "maxLength":255,
            "inclusion":"available",
            "type":[
               "null",
               "string"
            ]
         },
         "updated_at":{
            "inclusion":"available",
            "type":[
               "string"
            ],
            "format":"date-time"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

mongo catalog.json

```
{
 "streams": [
{
  "table_name": "users",
  "stream": "users",
  "metadata": [
    {
      "breadcrumb": [],
      "metadata": 
       {
       "selected": true,
       "replication-method": "FULL_TABLE",
        "table-key-properties": [
          "_id"
        ],
        "database-name": "efuse",
        "row-count": 434,
        "is-view": false,
        "valid-replication-keys": [
          "_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "tap_stream_id": "efuse-users",
  "schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "_id": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  }
 }
]
```

mongo config.json

```
{
 "password": "root",
 "user": "stitch_root",
 "host": "localhost",
 "port": 27017,
 "database": "admin",
 "ssl": "false",
 "replica_set": "rs0"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code. What you have tried already. It is almost impossible to give you valid answers just based on an error message.

Comment: @Christopher I have an update instruction. I have one table in mongodb users which i want to export to redshift. Let me know if you need anything more on it

Comment: @Christopher ? any suggestion?